# How can I replace property names inside of an object? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

My task is to create a function that swaps the names inside of the object with the names inside of an array.
Daniel's name should change to Felix and his age should remain the same. In the end, the object should look like this.

```
{Felix:18,Carlos:21,Sasha:22,John:20}
```

From This

```
{Daniel:18,Tyler:21,Michelle:22,Austin:20}
```

Heres what I have so far. I am new to programming so please try to take it easy on me.

```
function swapNames(oldNames,newNames){
  for(var i in oldNames) {
    for(var k = 0; k < newNames.length; k++) {
      i = newNames[k];
  }
}
  console.log(i)
}

swapNames({Daniel:18,Tyler:21,Michelle:22,Austin:20}, 
["Felix","Carlos","Sasha","John"])
```

I thought this would loop through the object and the array and set the objects property name to the current string I am on. But when I console.log() the object is exactly the same.

Comment: i m not sure, if your code is compiling  / getting parsed correct. In the code, you are not returning any thing or swapping any object keys. I have updated a way to get it done, if that helps you to understand , how you could do.

Comment: I don't really think you can do it safely, since properties order is not guaranteed in Javascript. Use an ```Array``` instead.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio What do you mean by property order is not guaranteed? Can you post a link explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you could do.

```js
const swapNames = (inputObj, outputNames) => {
  const output = {};
  Object.keys(inputObj).forEach((key, index) => {
    output[outputNames[index]] = inputObj[key];
  });
  return output;
}
console.log(swapNames({
  Daniel: 18,
  Tyler: 21,
  Michelle: 22,
  Austin: 20
}, ["Felix", "Carlos", "Sasha", "John"]));
```

Comment: What do the brackets around output[outputNames[index]] do? What is the purpose of using the brackets?

Comment: This is a way to access objects in javascript. More detailed information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Bro! Thank you so much! I never knew this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't want give away the answer, but your problem is here

```
for(var i in oldNames) {
    // when i = Daniel;
    for(var k = 0; k < newNames.length; k++) {
      i = newNames[k];
      // you loop here keep change i from Daniel to "Felix","Carlos","Sasha","John", 
      // then you go back to above loop and repeat this, so all four old name got stuck with John 
    }

    console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: Ah! I understand ok. I am resetting the name every time and since John is the last one i is left as John, right?